# Identify which control has invalid data + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have few controls on Angular Js form and submit button. I am also validating if the fields are empty or not. However, even when all data are entered, the form is not getting submitted. Below is the sample code which I have:

Index.cshtml

```
<body class="ng-cloak">
<div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">
<form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate="">
  <div class="container" ng-show="createMenu">             

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label>Name :</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="150" class="input-md form-control col-md-4" required="" ng-model="testName" name="testName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.testName.$error.required">Name is required</span>
//other controls
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitted=true" />
```

Is there any identifier or way to check which control has invalid data?
Thanks

Comment: Checkout the property `mainForm.$error`. See [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$error)

Comment: where should this be used? How to use it

Comment: Depends where you want it. You can for debugging purposes just add an element somewhere: `<pre ng-bind="mainForm.$error | json"></pre>`

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Could you please change the comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging purposes you can just print out [the `$error` property of the form controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$error):

```
<pre ng-bind="mainForm.$error | json"></pre>
```

This will immediately show you which model isn't valid.